# Fittype with 2D data

Tags: matlab, matrix, data-fitting

I have a surface defined by a matrix nxn. The x axis of the surface is a 1xn vector, and the y axis is another 1xn vector. My goal is to make a function to gives me the bests x_approx vector and y_approx vector that, interpolating the matrix, gives the minimum error.
If n is a big number (like 1000, for a surface with a big resolution) and I want to find a 10x10 matrix that represent this surface as best as posible, I need to do something like that. At this moment (for a 10x10 fit), I have this code:

```
ft = fittype(@(x,y)customizedFitFunction([x,y],k0,k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8,k9,q0,q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9),'numindep',2);
```

where x and y are the axis of the matrix, and k_i q_i are the best values for x and y axis, respectively. The data of the surface (z) is loaded into customizedFitFunction.

But when I execute this code, I have an error:
Error using fittype>iDeduceCoefficients (line 640)
This expression has no coefficients or non-scalar coefficients.

Any help?